# Performance impact when UseLayoutRounding = true

Tags: silverlight, performance, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-4.0

I'm wondering if there is any impact on performance when I will set UseLayoutRounding = true for almost all controls in my LOB application.

Especially texts looks bad if there is no layout rounding.

I'm working on Silverlight 3.0 but soon I'll migrate to 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware and in my limited experience, `UseLayoutRounding` has no performance consequences whatsoever.  Changing the value frequently, however, might be slow.

Comment: I will set it to TRUE in style so in this case no performance cost?

Comment: Benchmark it to be sure, but I'm virtually positive that is indeed the case.